# Easy way to get values from a website in C#

Tags: c#, regex, webclient

I have the following problem!
I want to get the shipping data from a website. They have the following structure:

[image]

The problem here is that there are multiple divs and in the divs there are more divs and tables.
Due to the fact i am a total noob with regular expressions, i wanted to know if there is any easier solution for grabbing the data.

Comment: Oh [you don't want to use regex for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1864167). Instead use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @AhmetKakıcı: may I quote you on that? That's a good one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: for proper attribution, see [here](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @JohnSaunders No that's not mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend walking the DOM using a framework like HTML Agility Pack rather than using regular expressions. Read here for more information: http://html-agility-pack.net

More specifically, when using HTML Agility Pack, as an alternative to manual DOM-traversal, you can use XPaths to define the elements you want to get the data from. You can write pretty resiliant XPaths that will identify the correct elements even when they're moved-around or formatted differently (e.g. attributes in a different order). Think of XPaths as being like CSS selectors but more powerful and with a steeper learning-curve.

As for regex, [you have been warned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: If you'd rather use CSS selectors, you can always use CsQuery: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery